# Getting "jQuery is not defined" when using a library that depends on it

Tags: scala.js, scalajs-bundler

I am trying to use the [bootstrap input spinner](https://github.com/shaack/bootstrap-input-spinner) in my scalajs app. But when I try to use it I am getting the error "jQuery is not defined", even though I have included it in my project. Can someone tell me what I am missing?

So if I define a build.sbt:

```
name := "repro"
version := "1.0"
scalaVersion := "2.12.8"                      

scalaJSUseMainModuleInitializer := true       
mainClass in Compile := Some("App")   
enablePlugins(ScalaJSPlugin)
enablePlugins(ScalaJSBundlerPlugin)

webpackBundlingMode := BundlingMode.LibraryOnly()

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
"org.querki" %%% "jquery-facade" % "1.2"
)

npmDependencies in Compile ++= Seq(
    "bootstrap" -> "4.3.1",
    "jquery" -> "3.2.1",
    "bootstrap-input-spinner" -> "1.11.8",
)
```

And then try to use it in my app as follows:

```
@js.native

trait BootstrapInputSpinner extends JQuery {
def inputSpinner(options: js.Object = js.Dynamic.literal()): BootstrapInputSpinner = js.native
}

object BootstrapInputSpinner {
@JSImport("bootstrap-input-spinner", JSImport.Default)
@js.native
object Import extends BootstrapInputSpinner
val _import = Import  // explicitly import it

implicit def bisExtensions(query: JQuery): BootstrapInputSpinner = 

query.asInstanceOf[BootstrapInputSpinner]
}


object App {

  import BootstrapInputSpinner._

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    $(dom.document.getElementById("spinner")).inputSpinner()
  }
}
```

My html file is defined as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test User interface</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>

<div class="app-container" id="root">
    <input id="spinner" type="number"/>
</div>

<script src="repro-fastopt-library.js"></script>
<script src="repro-fastopt-loader.js"></script>
<script src="repro-fastopt.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Note that if I don't refer to the bootstrap-input-spinner library and try to use jQuery on its own it works fine. For example there are no errors if I change my App object to:

```
object App {

//  import BootstrapInputSpinner._

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    println($(dom.document.getElementById("spinner")))
  }
}
```

Also, I checked the -library.js file and it has the following code:

```
module.exports = {
  "require": (function(x1) {
    return {
      "jquery": __webpack_require__(2),
      "bootstrap-input-spinner": __webpack_require__(3)
    }[x1]
  })
}
```

Which tells me that jquery should be imported first?

Comment: You probably have to also export jQuery to the global namespace as explained [here](https://scalacenter.github.io/scalajs-bundler/cookbook.html#global-namespace)

Answer (score 0):

I could guess from looking at the code, that you might need to add jQuery script too, before the library script that depend on.

Side note: You must check the compatibility of the bootstrap version and the jquery it depends

```
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="repro-fastopt-library.js"></script>
<script src="repro-fastopt-loader.js"></script>
<script src="repro-fastopt.js"></script>
```

Which of the scripts depend on jquery?

repro-fastopt-library or
repro-fastopt-loader or
repro-fastopt

It could be the import order when you bundle them.

Comment: Yes that would fix it but that is not how to do it with scalajs-bundler. I have declared jquery in my npmDepencencies and it does get added to the exports in the -library.js.

Comment: Can you look into to the bundled code if there is any reference to jquery?
Maybe the order in which is imported must change?

Comment: It could be the import order when you bundle them

Comment: No jquery appears first everywhere.

Comment: Can you run your html file and check in the console window if window.jQuery exists?
If its not there, that might be a sign

Comment: I would advice you to let jquery lib outside of your bundle, that is code you wont change and it can be cached independently by the browser

Comment: How can I do that in scala? dom.window does not have a jQuery property/

Comment: That would work but it is not the correct approach for using the scalajs-bundler surely?

Comment: That strategy is agnostic to any bundle tool. Lets suppose you update your code, it will generate a new bundle, the user will need to download all the jquery again, but you didnt change jquery, you only changed your code.

I'm pushing this approach mainly because it would solve your problem.